# MySQL: Select regex group

Tags: mysql, regex

Is there any way to get **regex** group from the string field?
Something like

```
SELECT REGEX_GROUP(`email`, '^.+@(.+)$', 0) AS email_host FROM test_table;
```

For example, field `email` looks like `'foo@bar'` and I want to get last part by `^.+@(.+)$` regex.

P.S. Actually regexps will be more difficult, email regexp is just for an example.

Comment: Does my workaround work for you?

Comment: @Jerry sorry, no. Look at P.S. section, it was just an example.

Comment: Oh... ok. I'll remove my answer then...